# How are input tensors with different shapes fed to neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/philtabor/Youtube-Code-Repository/blob/master/ReinforcementLearning/PolicyGradient/reinforce/reinforce_keras.py) on Policy Gradient using Keras,
and can't quite figure out the below.

In the below case, how exactly are input tensors with different shapes fed to the model?
Layers are neither `.concat`ed or `.Add`ed.

- `input1.shape = (4, 4)`
- `input2.shape = (4,)`
- "input" layer has 4 neurons, and accepts `input1` + `input2` as 4d vector??

The code excerpt (modified to make it simpler) :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4, ))
advantages = tf.keras.Input(shape=[1])
dense1 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(input)
dense2 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(dense1)
output = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(dense2)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input, advantages], outputs=[output])

# *********************************
input1 = np.array(
[[ 4.52281174e-02,  4.31672811e-02, -4.57789579e-02,  4.35560472e-02],
 [ 4.60914630e-02, -1.51269339e-01, -4.49078369e-02,  3.21451106e-01],
 [ 4.30660763e-02,  4.44624011e-02, -3.84788148e-02,  1.49510297e-02],
 [ 4.39553243e-02, -1.50087194e-01, -3.81797942e-02,  2.95249428e-01]]
)

input2 = np.array(
[ 1.60063125,  1.47153674,  1.34113826,  1.20942261]
)


label = np.array(
[[1, 0],
 [0, 1],
 [1, 0],
 [0, 1]]
)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005), loss="binary_crossentropy")
model.train_on_batch([input1, input2], label)
```

Comment: Lookup batch and sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where you might want to figure out what type of graph you have just build, it is helpful to use the `model.summary()` or `tf.keras.utils.plot_model()` methods for debugging:

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file="test.png", show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, show_dtype=True)
```

This will show you that your input_2 is indeed not used. Since you haven't connected it to the main graph with any operations, it has no weights associated with it (the graph runs but there is nothing to update on the right side):

[image]